# Window moves when clicking control in title region with titlebarAppearsTransparent

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, nscontrol

I have a window that uses the Yosemite `titlebarAppearsTransparent` and `titleVisibility = NSWindowTitleHidden` properties to extend the content under the title region.  It is also `movableByWindowBackground`.

This works fine, however if I have a control, e.g. `NSPopUpButton`, in the titlebar region, when I click and attempt to choose a menu item, the whole window moves (while the menu stays put).

Here's a demo:

[image: Imgur]

I've tried subclassing the `NSPopUpButton` and overriding `mouseDownCanMoveWindow`, but that doesn't help (it's called, but apparently ignored).

Any ideas?

---

**Edit**: I created a demo project to reproduce the issue.  It seems related to embedding the popup inside a `NSSplitViewController`.  I can't avoid that, though, so I'm not sure what the solution might be.

Here's the [demo project](http://www.dejal.com/files/2015/stackoverflow/hiddentitlesissuedemo.zip), if you want to try it.

---

**Edit 2**: apparently it is an OS bug, with no workaround.  [Filed Radar #21973457](http://www.openradar.me/21973457).